# Asynchronously submit multiple forms at once & gather server responses without AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, salesforce

One of our company's clients asked us to to update their existing web page which had 5 separate forms so that they could submit all of the forms with a single submit button. Normally this would be a relatively simple task using AJAX, or by simply combining the forms into a one; however their forms submit to the Salesforce web-to-case server which blocks AJAX requests, and using the JavaScript .submit() function 5 times will only successfully submit the last form.

The only solution I've currently found around this was to set the target of the forms to a hidden iframe, as shown here:

HTML

```
<form target="form5_frame" id="form1" method="post" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8">
    //inputs
</form>
<iframe name="form1_frame" src="" id="form1_frame" height="0"></iframe>
```

JavaScript

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    $('#form' + i).submit();
}
```

This will successfully submit all 5 forms to the Salesforce server, and the iframes populate with the server response.

The issue now, is that I'm unable to read the content of the responses in order to display success/error messages due to CORS cross-domain policy. I have gone into salesforce and added our domain to their CORS settings, and this didn't have an affect.

I had also heard about using postMessage functions in attached event listeners to communicate cross-domain, however the server response has it's own event listener attached to the body that blocks outgoing message events. The JavaScript code I tested with is:

```
//iframe event listener
$('#form1_frame').get(0).addEventListener('onload', function() {
    parent.postMessage("Hello!", "SITE DOMAIN HERE");
});

//message received code
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    var key = e.message ? "message" : "data";
    var data = e[key];
},false);
```

Is there anything else I can try in order to get around the cross domain issue, or even a better approach overall that doesn't use the iframe trick that might work?

Please let me know, and I'm more than happy to answer any questions.

Comment: CORS is not going to give you access to iframes. Basically you can't do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Use Promise.all()

Comment: @RadicalEdward and how would I implement that with multiple form submissions?

Comment: does it absolutely have to be web-to-case? can't you capture this serverside on your end and POST them manually to SF (or build proper integration with SF)

Comment: @eyescream Unfortunately, yes. They don't have the budget or time for a complete overhaul, especially server side.